# How to continue animation after stopping it

Tags: flash, animation, actionscript

I have an animation, in which a character is running in place. I also have a button that plays a rolling animation of the character. However after completing the rolling action  the character is stationary and doesn't continue the running animation. Here is the code.

```
package com.usmanzubairi.theAges
{

import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.net.SharedObject;

public class PirGame extends MovieClip
{

    public function PirGame() 
    {
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,rolling);
    }

    private function rolling (event:Event):void
    {
        if (event.target == roll_mc)
        {
            addChild(roll)
            roll.visible = true;
            runner_mc.visible = false;
            roll.play();
        }

    }

}
```

`}`

Basically, i want the running animation to continue playing after the rolling animation has completed. Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention, there is also a "stop();" action at the end of the running animation.

Comment: why don't you remove `stop();` action at the end of timeline??

Comment: If I remove the stop(); action, the running animation freezes (for a second) during the animation and continues playing. It doesn't hide.

Comment: you need to use setTimeout() instead of stop() action at the end of timeline and choose a reasonable time for it.